# Keep getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error

Tags: dns

I am trying to remove the DNS that I have set to 8.8.8.8 previously but cannot seem to see where it gets the DNS from.

In my wired connection I can see the DNS:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** resolv.conf contents:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search station
```

**EDIT 2:**
I found out that on the file ```/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`` I had the following:

`supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;`

which I uncommented and the **8.8.8.8** from my Wire Connection is now gone and has been replaced with **192.168.2.1**.
After trying your command:

`sudo systemd-resolve -i enp4s0 --set-dns=192.168.2.1`

I keep getting the error **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** occasionally when I try to go to different websites

How do I resolve this from keep appearing as it keeps my productivity low with the need to wait for 5-10 seconds for a website to load?

Comment: Is the DNS possibly supplied by a DHCP  server?

Comment: Can you post the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`? You can do it opening a terminal and writing `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't think so, some time ago I tried adding Google DNS due to a DNS error I was getting in my browser(dns_probe_finished_nxdomain) which I keep getting and I am trying to remove the DNS servers from the connection to see if it helps resolve this issue

Comment: @balon I have edited the question with the contents of the ```resolv.conf``` file

Comment: 192.168.2.1 is a private IP address. Unless you have a DNS in your local network, it won't work. Real DNS have real IP addresses (like 8.8.8.8 (dns.google)).

Answer (score 1):

`resolv.conf` indeed contains the DNS-servers that should be used. But ubuntu now uses systemd which provides it's own DNS-server.

`127.0.0.53` is (just like `127.0.0.1`) your own system, so `resolv.conf` forces your system to contact it's own (systemd) dns-server. This systemd dns-server will send the requests to 'real' DNS-server(s).

You can change the final dnsserver(s) that systemd uses with:

`systemd-resolve -i NETWORKINTERFACE --set-dns=SOMESERVER`

Systemd allows you to use different settings for each networkconnection, which is why you also have to specify the network-interface.

Suppose you want to make sure that all dns-requests that are sent out on interface `eth0` are being sent to `8.8.8.8`, then the command becomes `systemd-resolve -i eth0 --set-dns=8.8.8.8`.

You can run this command for multiple interfaces if you need to make sure that in all these cases the same dns-server is being used.

See `systemd-resolve --status` for the current settings and `man systemd-resolve` for everything there is to know about configuring systemd's DNS-server.

PS: You will probably already know this, but I'll mention it anyway: Replace `SOMESERVER` by a IP-address instead of a name, because otherwise you would have a circular problem

Comment: Running ```systemd-resolve --set-dns=192.168.x.x``` throws the following error: ```--set-dns=, --set-domain=, --set-llmnr=, --set-mdns=, --set-dnssec=, --set-nta= and --revert require --interface=.```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to specify the network interface with `-i INTERFACE`, i'll edit my answer

Comment: A little late on my reply, but I found out that on the file ```/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf``` I had the following: ```supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;``` which I uncommented and the ```8.8.8.8``` from my Wire Connection is now gone and has been replaced with ```192.168.2.1```. After trying your command: ```sudo systemd-resolve -i enp4s0 --set-dns=192.168.2.1``` I still get the error ```DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN``` occasionally when I try to go to different websites